# How do I change an onmouseover event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML span which changes it's class onmouseover and onmouseout:

```
<span id="someSpan" class="static" onmouseover="this.className='active'" onmouseout="this.className='static'">Some Text</span>
```

I want to be able to enable and disable (change) the onmouseover and onmouseout events using a Javascript function called elsewhere on the page. Is this Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

```
document.getElementById('someSpan').onmouseover = 
     function() { 
         this.className='newactive'; 
     };
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to accept this answer and Jason's. This works as desired for my prototype but I'll be looking at how to do this using JQuery later on.

Answer (score 1):

The safe way is to use a Javascript toolkit like Prototype or JQuery.

They all can do things like this easily but it works cross-browser.

For example, [here is how you do it in JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events).

Answer (score 1):

I would agree jQuery would be easier, but if you would like to stick to JavaScript, I believe this should work:

document.getElementById("elementId").onMouseOut=functionName;

Additionally, jQuery is about 20Kb in size (size of production framework file), so it might slow down the loading of your page. Something to consider if you're just using it for a few things that may be done in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that simply by assigning to the onmouseover and onmouseout properties of the Element instance for the span, e.g.:

```
// Define your handler somewhere
function myNewHandler()
{
    // ...new logic...
}

// And where you want to swap it in:
document.getElementById('someSpan').onmouseover = myNewHandler;
```

...but this is a fairly old-fashioned way to do this.  A more modern approach uses addEventListener or attachEvent (depending on whether you're doing standard or IE) to hook up event handlers.  Libraries like Prototype, jQuery, and about a dozen others can help.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
document.getElementById("someSpan").onmouseover = function()
{
    //New code
};//Do not forget the semicolon
```