# How do i add the onmouseover event to alert 'no escape... '

Tags: javascript

```
<body>

<h1 id= hi >TOUCH!</h1>

</body>
```

I don't know how to do it and I can't find a suitable answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change an onmouseover event using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288022/how-do-i-change-an-onmouseover-event-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("hi").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
alert("foo");
});
```

```html
<h1 id= hi >TOUCH!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the title attribute.

```
<body>

<h1 title="No escape" id="hi">TOUCH!</h1>

</body>
```